# Change of covariance under Lipschitz maps

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, st.statistics

Consider a finite point set $X$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and a $1$-Lipschitz map  $\,f:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$.

Is it true that the maximum eigenvalue of the centered covariance matrix of $f(X)$ is at most the maximum eigenvalue of the centered covariance matrix of $X$?

Comment: Do I understand it right that $f$ is Lipschitz in the entire space, $f(0)=0$ and by the covariance matrix of the set $X_j$ you mean the matrix with entries $a_{i,j}=\langle X_i,X_j\rangle$?

Comment: $f$ is globally Lipschitz yes, but the covariance is the centered covariance (so no need to fix the image of the origin). edited the text. Also the matrix you describe is the Gram matrix, not the covariance, but it has the same non zero eigenvalues as the *non centered* covariance matrix

Comment: Just meaning you subtract the center of mass before taking scalar products? (sorry for stupid questions; I just think that to ask is easier than to guess or to google :-) )

Comment: yes, that's what I mean by centering. Then you can take scalar products instead of covariance if you prefer

Comment: Then the answer is "no". Let $e_j$ be some orthonormal set ($j=1,\dots,n$).Take all pairs $e_j,-e_j$ and $2n$ zero vectors. Define $f(x)=\|x\|$ (mapping to $\mathbb R^1$). If $n$ is not too small, you are in trouble.

Comment: can't be right, for mappings to the line the result is true. I do tend to think the result is false in general though

Comment: Then we have a language barrier and I don't understand what you are asking. In my understanding, the original covariance matrix is of norm $2$. The new one contains an $2n\times 2n$ block of $1/4$. Now, what is your interpretation of this example?

Comment: in any case, in this example, the image point set has $2n$ zeroes and $2n$ ones, so maximum eigenvalue of covariance is a quarter

Comment: As I said, language barrier. What is the full covariance matrix then (and is it $4n\times 4n$)?

Comment: One wild guess: don't you, by chance, think that the English word "eigenvalue" means "a matrix entry" (i.e., some $a_{ij}$)? That would explain a lot in our conversation.

Comment: ok, now I think your example works. I confused with something else for the 1d case. Thanks!